# Proper way to string interpolate an array element within printf

Tags: arrays, perl, string-interpolation

While working on Schwartz's *Learning Perl*, I came across an exercise where I am supposed to accept a number of user input strings, where the first input is to be the width determining right justified output for the other strings.

In other words, inputs:

```
10
apple
boy
```

Output should be:

```
       10
    apple
      boy
```

where output is right justified by 10.

I tried using arrays to approach the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array;
while (<>) {
    chomp($_);
    push @array, $_ ;
}

while (@array) {
    printf ("%$array[0]s \n", shift @array);
}
```

But after formatting and printing '10' correctly, I get errors:

```
$ perl test.pl 
10
apple
boy
        10 
Invalid conversion in printf: "%a" at test.pl line 11, <> line 3.
%apples 
Argument "boy" isn't numeric in printf at test.pl line 11, <> line 3.
0oys
```

I tried a variety of methods to force interpolation of the array element by enclosing it in braces, but all these have resulted in errors. What's the proper way to string interpolate array elements within printf (if that's the right term)?

Comment: `printf ("%$array[0]s \n", $_) for @array;`

Comment: That does work properly. Could you explain why what I was doing was wrong?

Comment: You were destroying array from left side with `shift`

Comment: Ah. So I destroyed the first element that was supposed to control printf formatting!

Comment: @Droidzone: Note that `printf` formatting allows you to pass the field width as a parameter `printf "%*s\n", $array[0], $_ for @array`

Comment: @Borodin, really? I thought that worked just for precision of numbers.

Comment: @Droidzone: The value before the format specifier means different things for different specifiers, but you can replace any value there with an asterisk `*` and it will be provided from the parameter list. You can specify *both* the field width *and* the precision if you like, like this `perl -e "printf '%*.*f', 8, 4, 3.14159"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more Perlish way to write it that avoids having to perform an explicit `shift`. It's a lot more do-what-I-mean since the format control variable is not part of `@array` from the start:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $length, @array ) = <>;
chomp( $length, @array );

printf "%${length}s\n", $_ for ( $length, @array );
```